# Do battlestars have a secondary CIC?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Do the battlestars in the TOS or reimaged series have a secondary CIC/bridge? I know that in Star Trek the larger ships have one, like the Auxiliary Control room (TOS), or the Battle Bridge (TNG). Is it because the battlestars have better protection in the reimaged version? (The bridge was on the top part toward the front of the alligator head in the original series and was prone to damage easier.)

Comment: Star Trek TNG, the Enterprise iirc could also use Main Engineering as a make shift bridge

Comment: I don’t recall seeing an auxiliary CIC on any battlestar blueprints or cross-sections. One could assume they are highly protected in the thickest armor on the ship, although one could also assume that systems can be manually individually controlled elsewhere in the ship as evidenced by Tyrol’s action during Felix’s coup on Galactica, and also Garner’s sacrificial actions on Pegasus.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan in the re-imagined series, in "Razor" iirc it was mentioned that anything can be controlled from anywhere on the ship. I don't think that relied on the CNP program being installed